# Erro ao incluir mais de um dado mysql em funcao javascript intel XDK com PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql-insert, intel-xdk

Estou usando a seguinte função:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $server;
    $server = 'http://localhost/mobile/DatabaseXDK/database/www/';

    $('#inclusao').on('click', function(){
        $nome = $('#nome').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: $server+"/conexao.php",
            timeout: 3000,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "nome="+$nome+"&acao=inclusao",
            success: function(data) {
                intel.xdk.notification.alert('Pessoa Cadastrada!','Inclusao','ok');
                Pessoas();
            }
        });
    });
```

Até ai beleza, roda perfeito, mas se eu coloco mais algum campo como, sobrenome, não inclui nada no sobrenome. Vejam a função:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var $server;
    $server = 'http://localhost/mobile/DatabaseXDK/database/www/';

    $('#inclusao').on('click', function(){
        $nome = $('#nome').val();
        $sobrenome = $('#sobrenome').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: $server+"/conexao.php",
            timeout: 3000,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "nome="+$nome+"sobrenome"+sobrenome+"&acao=inclusao",
            success: function(data) {
                intel.xdk.notification.alert('Pessoa Cadastrada!','Inclusao','ok');
                Pessoas();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Não deveria ser `"nome="+$nome+"&sobrenome"+sobrenome+"&acao=inclusao"` veja que tem um `&` antes do sobrenome.

Comment: Parece que vc esqueceu do cifrão e do & "nome="+$nome+"&sobrenome"+$sobrenome+"&acao=inclusao",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acredito que esteja faltando um `&` na sua função.

```
nome="+$nome+"&sobrenome"+sobrenome+"&acao=inclusao"
```

A cada campo que você for inserindo a mais tem que ir colocando o `&` nas outras variáveis.